# React context work without actual component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Just when I thought I understood contexts, I don't again. I created a database context, mostly for no reason since it's a global that can be just used as a var, but I digress. I wanted to be React-y. Anyway the component looks like this

```
import { createContext, useContext } from "react";
import { Database } from "../lib/database/Database";

const db = new Database();

export interface DatabaseContextValues {
  db: Database;
}

export const DatabaseContext = createContext<DatabaseContextValues>({
  db,
});

export const DatabaseContextProvider: React.FC = (props) => {
  return (
    <DatabaseContext.Provider value={{ db }}>
      {props.children}
    </DatabaseContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useDatabaseContext = () => useContext(DatabaseContext);
```

And on a random component I used it like this

```
export const MyThing = () => {
   const { db } = useDatabaseContext();
}
```

And it worked. And I thought great. And then some time later, I realized I never even created the component itself, eg in my `App`

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      // woops, forgot provider, but doesn't matter
      <MyThing/>
    </SafeAreaProvider> 
  )
}
```

What am I not understanding or doing wrong?

Comment: Context is not just like a global variable, it provides an easy way to modify what that global variable is by passing different contexts.

Comment: I think its because of where you are calling`useContext`,  I always used `useContext` hook inside my consuming component, not in Provider file itself because its a "hook" not just an ordinary function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The provider role is to centralize and dispatch the context values for all children components. If you don't wrap child components in the provider, they will access to a new, 'unshared' context.

Comment: Ah, I see. Although in this case it would be the same database since it was declared outside of the context.

Comment: Do you have a link that documents this behavior?